# Spring Boot Maven Plugin isn't being recognized in Plugin Tags

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot

I'm trying to install the spring boot maven plugin and it doesn't seem to be working. The error comes with the build tags. Intellij isn't recognizing **'sprint-boot-maven-plugin' inside the plugin tag** and I'm not sure why. Intelli recognizes i in a dependency tag, but they aren't allowed inside the build tags. Please Help!

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
<artifactId>gs-spring-boot</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.6.RELEASE</version>
</parent>


<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.6.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>


<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<build>

    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.6.RELEASE</version>

        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Answer (score 3):

Dependency tag should be inside `<dependencies>` tag, not `<project>`:

```
...
</parent>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<properties>
...
```

Comment: I'm not getting an error with my dependency. I'm getting an error with my artifactId tag not recognizing 'spring-boot-maven-plugin' inside the plugin tag

Comment: IntelliJ is sometimes not very accurate about the exact spot for XML errors; still, your POM won't even process properly without the change above, so I'd suggest fixing that first, and seeing if the error goes away (EDIT: according to my IntelliJ, there are no other errors in your POM)

Comment: Ah I see. I added the <dependencies> tag and still no luck. I'm actually seeing another error at the top of my pom.xml ==> Failure to transfer org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:pom:2.0.6.RELEASE from https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced.

Comment: You can try to force Maven to update the dependency by running with an `-U` flag, or just delete the local dependency and rebuild. Local repo is at the `%USERPROFILE%\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-parent` by default - just delete the `2.0.6.RELEASE` folder there